# Bash String char assignment using position index

Tags: bash

Is it possible to change the string char using position index.
For ex:

```
Myvar="abcd"
```

`echo ${Myvar:0:1}` gives the first char 'a'
Can I change the first char to 'z'?

Simply trying to assign variable to {Myvar:0:1} didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`, the stream editor, you can do

```bsh
echo $Myvar | sed s/./z/0
```

Otherwise, you can do it directly by

```bsh
Myvar="abcd"
len=`expr length "$Myvar"`
len=$((len-1))
Ind=2
character="z"

if [[ $Ind -eq 0 ]]
then
    Myvar="$character${Myvar:1}"
elif [[ $Ind -eq $len ]]
then
    Myvar="${Myvar:0:$((len-1))}$character"
else
    Myvar="${Myvar:0:$Ind}$character${Myvar:$((Ind+1))}"
fi
echo $Myvar
```

However, as you can see, it is much less elegant, and it is better if you just use `sed`

Comment: can you elaborate Myvar="z${Myvar:1}"

Comment: Yes, it makes Myvar = 'z' + Myvar after index 1, which means it replaced the first character

Comment: I see. How would this work for replacing character in 2nd position? This is basically appending, correct?

Comment: Yes. For second character, for example, it assigns Myvar = (Myvar from 0 to 1) + A + (Myvar after index 3)

Comment: I was hoping to do this in a loop. Like- For i in {0..3}; do {myvar:$i:0}=z; done

Comment: Like you do in contemporary programming problems, right?

Comment: IDK if this is possible, as you can not assign {myvar:$i:0}

Comment: However this all can be  easily compressed into a bash script, I'll update the answer with the script

Comment: I ended up using a for loop based on your answer...just concatenation using a loop.